# How I can track if users closes tab and show him research window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, for example. I want to track if user leaves the landing page without doing anything (not just leaves, closes tab), and stop closing, show him form with several questions for research. (if he clicks close again or submits the form tab should be closed). 
Is it possible?
May be some hints how this can be done? I know most of browsers have some protection from spaming user with alerts and so on.

Comment: the OnBeforeUnload event? or OnUnload?  not sure if this gets hit when closing a tab though

Comment: This is not possible. If you're lucky you can show a standard dialog with OK or Cancel button by adding an `onunload` handler.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this

```
    function formIsDirty(form) {
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        var element = form.elements[i];
        var type = element.type;
        if (type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") {
            if (element.checked != element.defaultChecked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (type == "hidden" || type == "password" ||
                 type == "text" || type == "textarea") {
            if (element.value != element.defaultValue) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (type == "select-one" || type == "select-multiple") {
            for (var j = 0; j < element.options.length; j++) {
                if (element.options[j].selected !=
                    element.options[j].defaultSelected) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            if (!formIsDirty(document.getElementById(formId))) {
                // For IE and Firefox
                if (e) {
                    e.returnValue = message;
                }
                // For Safari
                return message;
            }
        };
```