# Session issue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session

I am facing the below issue while executing the asp.net application.

1) I have 1000 records from database, and  i am placing the these 1000 records in session to
   send this data to Message queue.

2) This process is done in a foreach loop, and I opened one more tab and closed the existing browser.

3) even I close the browser tab, still the process is sending my records to the message queue.

4) I placed session.abandom() also, but still problem persists.

Please suggest on this.

Comment: How are you managing your session state? i.e inproc, out of proc

Comment: 1000 records in session??? That's almost abuse of sessions

Comment: As far as i understand your question, you want to kill session on browser close, please refer to this link ; http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed. Please note the difference between closing a tab and closing browser

Answer (score 1):

You can do a callback when the browser is closed...

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
function onClose()
{
    window.location="http://www.yourdomain.com/KillSessions.ashx";
} 
</SCRIPT>

<body onunload="onClose()">
```

The handler would then have specific code to kill all the sessions. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608835/how-i-can-track-if-users-closes-tab-and-show-him-research-window) is also helpful to track closing tabs/windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not on the session, because the current process will continue his job and after that the session will end. so try to kill the current thread and not to end session.